# When is a prop defined, equal to what was passed to the component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have some unreliable behaviour of my component to which a `prop` is passed that I want to debug:

```
<my-component :number="someNumber" />
```

`number` is made available in `my-component` via a standard `prop: ["number"]` declaration.

**My question**: at which point of the reactivity cycle is `number` defined to the value of `someNumber` in the parent?

Specifically, I need to make some actions when `number` has the correct value (I assume that it is `undefined` before that). I can do that in:

- `created()`,
- `mounted()`,
- or by watching `number`

Which is the correct approach? (i.e. the one where `number` has the value that is passed to the component).

---

My current findings are that:

- on the first use of a component `watch` is OK, in `mounted()` the value is `undefined`
- on subsequent uses of the component, `watch` does not trigger (when the same value is passed), but `mounted()` now has the proper value.

So my workaround will be to use both (with some checks against `undefined`) but it looks really shaky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is available in the `data()` which happens before `created`. Literally only place where you can define some code to be executed by Vue where props are not available is `beforeCreated` [lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks)

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
  props: ["p"],
  data() {
    return {
      d: this.p
    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log("created:", this.p, this.d)
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("mounted:", this.p, this.d)
  },
  template: `<div>{{ p }} {{ d }}</div>`
})

const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
   data() {
    return {
      v: 10
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"> 
  <my-component :p="v"></my-component>
</div>
```